# Why consecutive socket.makefile calls lost incoming informantion?

Tags: python, sockets

```
# server side
import socket, time

with socket.socket() as sock:
    sock.bind(('', 27182))
    sock.listen()
    _sock = sock.accept()[0]
for _ in range(3):
    time.sleep(3)
    with _sock.makefile() as file:
        print(repr(file.readline()))
```

This is the server side code ,which reads incoming messages line by line every three seconds .

```
# client side
import socket, time

with socket.socket() as sock:
    sock.connect(('127.0.0.1', 27182))
    for s in b'aaa\n', b'bbb\n', b'ccc\n':
        sock.sendall(s)
        time.sleep(2)
```

This is the client side code ,which sends messages line by line every two seconds .

```
'aaa\n'
'ccc\n'
''
```

This is the output of the server side ,which confuses me ,because parts of the messages send from the client side has been lost .Why is this happening ?

Comment: Why are you calling `.makefile()` multiple times?  It's likely that the file-like objects being returned are reading all the available data into an internal buffer, before splitting off the first complete line - so when you create a new object, you throw away everything buffered by the previous object.

Comment: @jasonharper After passing buffering =0 argument to makefile() ,all is fine now .